# What is the difference between a Web-Service and a Application-Service

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, amazon-web-services

This might be a silly question on this site, but I want to learn more about it.

Being in the Software Engineering field, I have come to know that it's useful to get acquainted with Web-Services. I am trying to understand it. To do so, I must know the difference between a Web-Service and a Application-Service in simple terms.

I have heard about **SOAP** & **REST Services**.

For a newbie like me, its overwhelming to understand these concepts when I search them in Google.

How to understand these things *better* and in *what order*?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a great and simple question which usually confuses most of developers. What is Application Service and what is web Service?

Web service is a common term which you can find easily on the internet. Although some time they cross each others boundaries but here is a simplest explanation I can think of:

1. `Application service or Application Layer` is an abstraction layer reserved for communications protocols and methods designed for process-to-process communications. Application layer protocols use the underlying transport layer protocols to establish host-to-host connections.
   Some time you can also use Application Service to define method calls within your application.
2. `WebService:` Any application or method which can be accessed by web is a Webservice. You can also say: anything available on the web is WebService.

There are three common web service architectures:

1. RESTful resource-oriented,
2. RPC-style e.g. **SOAP**
3. REST-RPC hybrid. 90% of the web sites use this unknowingly e.g. http://mysite.com/get/pictures?tag=birthday :)